# How can I merge/sum together a range of rows in a pandas DataFrame into one row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, rows

I have a pandas DataFrame and I am trying to sum together and merge the last several rows into a single row. Is there a way I can specify an index range and have that range of rows summed and merged into a single row across all the columns?

[image: Current and Expected Dataframe]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to *specify an index range and have that range of rows summed and merged into a single row across all the columns*:

```
start_row = 18

df.iloc[start_row] = df.iloc[start_row:].sum()
df = df.iloc[:start_row+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I assume your data has only two columns (count & percent):

```
df.reset_index().replace({'index':[i for i in range(18,24)]}, {'index':18}).groupby('index', as_index=False).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with a lambda function:

```
start = 18
df = df.groupby(lambda x: x if x < start else start).sum()
```